# php mail() doesn't send e-mail with images from particular host

Tags: php, wordpress, email, html-email

I'm  trying to send html e-mail. When I'm sending e-mail without images or with images from another domains, it's working fine. But when I'm putting image from my host, it doesn't send e-mail at all.

I have tried send e-mail from another host using images from my domain, it seems like working.

Does anybody had similar issue and how can I tackle it?

EDIT: here is the function, wich I use.

```
function send_html_email($email = '', $template, $subject = '', $data = array()) {

    /* email header */
    ob_start();
    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/email-templates/header.php';
    $header = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    /* email content */
    ob_start();
    require TEMPLATEPATH . "/email-templates/{$template}.php";
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    /* email footer */
    ob_start();
    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/email-templates/footer.php';
    $footer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    $message = $header . $content . $footer;

    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html';     

    return wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

}
```

I have tried with `wp_mail()` and `mail()` functions, both are returning `true`.

Comment: Some code might come in handy

Comment: What is the content type of the mail you have assigned

Comment: did you try looking at the mail log on your server?

Comment: "php mail() doesn't send e-mail" What does happen? Does `mail()` return `false`? Also `If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime.` from PHP docs.

Comment: I'm setting header with `'Content-type: text/html'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't reinvent the wheel!**

Sending advanced mail, hardcoding them into HTMLs mail() function is a tedious task.

Instead you should use something like [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or use the PEAR package [PEAR::Mail_Mime](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/15/5/2).

This since there is quite a few pitfalls to circumvent if you write your scripts yourself.

Comment: But what's the differense? It sends emails with images from other hosts. It doesn't work when I'm tring to put into e-mail site logo or user's avatar.

Comment: html mail are formatted in a different way then ordinary (plaintext) mails. Explanging exactly how this works won't fit this format. You should look up how MIME multipart emails work. Maybe this: https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-13/email-parsing-and-composing will point you in the right direction